# Using a Specific Animation in ViewPager

Tags: android, user-interface, animation

today i was looking for a good way to create animation on ViewPager and i found a good library in github named SparkleMotion . i saw a animation in their demo that a paper playn fly and leave a trace behind . Here's how its look 
https://github.com/IFTTT/SparkleMotion/blob/master/art/sparklemotion.gif
in fact i only need the trace animation behind the plane and not other animation , can anyone tell me what is this animation and how to use it ?
the github link of the project is :
https://github.com/IFTTT/SparkleMotion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code in that SparkleMotion project you will be most interested in is the [`PathAnimation` class](https://github.com/IFTTT/SparkleMotion/blob/master/sparklemotion/src/main/java/com/ifttt/sparklemotion/animations/PathAnimation.java) in the main project and the [`PaperPlaneView` class](https://github.com/IFTTT/SparkleMotion/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/ifttt/sparklemotiondemo/PaperPlaneView.java) in the demo project.

The animation is centered on the [`android.graphics.Path` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html).  With the `Path` class, you can string together straight lines, arcs, rectangles, bezier curves, etc. to form a continuous line.

To render a path, the `Canvas` class has a `drawPath()` method.  It also has a related method `setPathEffect()` where you could for example set a `DashPathEffect` to get the dashed lines.

What makes the animation work is a class called `PathMeasure`.  A `PathMeasure` object takes a `Path` in its constructor. This allows you to do measuring operations on the `Path`.  By calling `PathMeasure.getSegment()` you can get a portion of the path, so by getting longer and longer segments, you can animate the path in motion.  And the demo uses the `PathMeasure.getPosTan()` method to get the position and tangent of the end of the segment.  These values are used to position and rotate the paper airplane graphic to look like it is traveling on the path.